# Rails 3.0 bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

"rails new app" command is generating two rails applications namely "new" and "app"  but both of them doesn't contains Gemfile, due to which I am not being  able to run "bundle" command by changing current directory to either of the applications. I am using "rvm use 1.9.2" command to have ruby 1.9.2 and the more "gem list" command also shows bundle and bundler.

so any help .

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using a old Rails2 "rails" binary.
Give `rails --version` a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple versions of Rails installed you'll have trouble with which binary is being used.

Check if you have both `2.3.x` and `3.0.x` installed by running `gem list`.

If you need both versions, you'll want to [create gemsets for each rails version](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/) in rvm. Then you do something like `rvm use 1.9.2@rails2` or `rvm use 1.9.2@rails3` to specify which gemset you want to use.